# “Save to Files” on iOS (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to save email attachments to my app’s doc folder (C++ FMX app for iOS & Android).  How do I register my app as a target?

The screen shots below show that an app on my phone named Termius is a target to save files to.  I want my app to be a target like this.  Just need user to get files into my app folder.

[image: popup to save doc]

[image: target to save to]
relayman

Comment: Have you checked out this tutorial? https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

Comment: Thanks Sherlock70, but i can't see how do what the tutorial shows in Rad Studio.  The `UIFileSharingEnabled` keys are not available under "Project->Options->Application->Version Info" and i can't see how to add them.    I have no idea how to implement this in C++ Builder.  This guys lays it out sweet for Swift though.

Comment: Well, now you know the basic method. What you need is a new or refined question of how to get the Swift solution into Delphi. And FYI you can enter your own keys into the Version Info ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Sherlock70 tutoring i was able to easily add my app's Documents folder as a "save to files" target.  I selected iOSDevice64 as my target platform and then went to "Project->Options->Application->Version Info" where i right-clicked and selected "Add Key" and added the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` key with their values set to `true`.

[image: snip showing the new keys]

Now i can save an email attachment to my app's Document folder via "Save to Files".  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959589/how-get-file-properties-with-firemonkey) shows how you can then list the files in your Documents folder.  Below is image showing what pops up when you click "Save to Files":

[image]

Note i'm working in Rad Studio 10.3 (C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.32429.4364).

UPDATE:  At iOS 13 Apple has moved the "Save to Files" icon.

[image]

And here it is:

[image]

Comment: The above works fine except for Release builds that you need to upload with the Application Loader.  The problem on a Release build is that the app store will reject the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key because it isn't formed correctly in the `Info.plist` file.  See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932283/uifilesharingenabled-key-in-info-plist/57936177#57936177) to see how to easily work around this problem.