# UIFileSharingEnabled key in Info.plist

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I added the key `UIFileSharingEnabled` to my app's version info [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030724/save-to-files-on-ios-fmx/56091607#56091607) so my users can save files to my apps documents folder.  Works great in testing.  Tried to upload to apple store with Application Loader and i'm getting an `ERROR ITMS-90039: "Type Mismatch. The value for the Info.plist key UIFileSharingEnabled is not of the required type for that key.`.  I've googled and found where other folks had problems with it but none of their solutions helped.  Here are the ways i've tried to show this key in the Info.plist:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<string>true</string>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<string>YES</string>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<YES/>
```

All have the same result, Application Loader barfs out the `ERROR ITMS-90039`.   This key is a boolean key and for other boolean keys in Info.plist they just look like that top one i show.   Anyone have a sample Info.plist with this key true that we can compare too?

I've built my app in Rad Studio 10.3.2 (C++ Builder).  They key works with test builds on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working and here is the deal:  The `Info.plist` file in the `iOSDevice64\Release` folder is just for your info, it is not what gets uploaded to apple in the Application Loader.  The `Info.plist` that gets uploaded is inside the [.ipa file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) that is created when you build a Release version in Rad Studio and it gets signed so you obviously can't modify it.

The solution was to [edit the](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Customizing_Your_info.plist_File) `info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml` that is in my app's project folder. The keys you put in `Project->Options-Application->Version Info` get added to this `info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml` when you build.  So, I edited this template file and put the correct key representation in between `<%ExtraInfoPListKeys%>` and the last `</dict>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<%VersionInfoPListKeys%>
<%ExtraInfoPListKeys%>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you just put the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in the `Project->Options-Application->Version Info` it will end up in the `Info.plist` like below which is wrong and Application Loader will give that error:

```
 <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
 <string>true</string>
```

The key must be like below to work on Release that you submit to app store:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```